# Ambiguous behaviour while returning reference value

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private static int Incr(ref int i)
    {
        return i++;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var i = 0;
        i += Incr(ref i);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Console.WriteLine(i) will gives us "0". But calling Incr(ref i) without "+="

```
var i = 0;
Incr(ref i);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

will give us "1". How is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of `i += Incr(ref i)` as

```
i = i + Incr(ref i);
```

In other words:

- Evaluate `i`
- Call `Incr(ref i)`
- Add the two operands together
- Assign to `i`

Now `Incr(ref i)` sets `i` to 1, but *returns* 0... so the sum ends up being 0 + 0, which is then assigned to `i`. The value of `i` is *very temporarily* 1, in the time between `Incr` returning and the result being assigned back to `i`.

If you had:

```
int j = i + Incr(ref i);
```

then you'd end up with `j=0, i=1`.

When you *just* call `Incr(ref i)` then `Incr` increments `i` (so `i` is 1) and then the return value is ignored... so `i` is 1 afterwards.

In other news: code like this should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @Anton23, the moral of this story is, don't use `ref`. Not only does it make the code harder to understand and maintain, it can lead to bugs due to this sort of behaviour.

Comment: There are plenty of legitimate uses for `ref`, hence why it is provided.  The `Interlocked` namespace uses `ref` (I don't think there's a sane way to implement that namespace without `ref`).  A better rule of thumb: 1) Don't use a `ref` variable twice in the same statement. 2) In order to avoid accidentally violating #1, only use `ref` for local variables.  Considering that properties cannot be passed with `ref`, these are easy rules to follow.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does:

- Compiler internal rewrite: `i += Incr(ref i);` becomes `i = i + Incr(ref i);` (that is what `+=` does after all).
- Evaluate `i +`. `i` is 0; **Result A**
- Call `Incr(ref i)` where `i` is 0;
- Return `i`. `i` is still 0. **Result B**
- Increment `i` by doing `i++` after the value was returned. Since `i` is passed as `ref`: `i` is 1 but  `i` is not playing any role in the evaluation since `i +` is already evaluated!
- Add Result A (0) to Result B (0). Result: 0.

Comment: That is what I say, right? *Return `i`. `i` is still 0. ... Increment afterwards.*

Comment: The result is that `i` is 0 though: `Console.WriteLine(i) will gives us "0"`. You've ignored the fact that `i+= foo` is equivalent to `i = i + foo`, so `i` is evaluated *before* `foo`.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing that out. Missed that. I guess it is fixed now.